# Send Bulk Email without them going to spam

Tags: email, bulk

I am trying to find a way so that I wont need to pay to MailChimp or any of these companies for my 6000+ users, I want to send them mails twice a month, so thats more than 12000 mails per month. Can I use my wordpress for this purpose?

How can I use my hosting server for this task?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I like sparkpost.  It's worth checking out and free under 100,000 emails a month.  I used to use Mandrill but once they were bought by mailchimp I switched to sparkpost and haven't looked back.

Comment: I have an external database, how can I import it to my hosting server, is that the way or completely wrong way?